# How to disable matched tag and parenthesis highlited line in vim?

Tags: vim

[image]

I have changed my vim colorscheme and after that all those white lines in matched tag are coming, I tried `:NoMatchParen` , in command  and `let loaded_matchparen=1` in vimrc but does not do anything.

I put this line in my colorscheme file also but no change

```
hi MatchParen ctermfg=232 ctermbg=232 "gui"="underline" guifg="111111" guibg="111111"
```

I am using spf13 vim on ubuntu 16.04,
Here is my vimrl.local

```
set t_Co=256
set laststatus=2
let base16colorspace=256
let g:onedark_termcolors=256
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
colorscheme Tomorrow-Night-Bright
" Enable the list of buffers
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
" Show just the filename

"hi MatchParen "111111","111111","bold","","111111"

hi MatchParen ctermfg=232 ctermbg=232 "gui"="underline" guifg="111111" guibg="111111"

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':t'
let g:airline_theme='onedark'
let g:onedark_use_term_italics = 1
:set list
:set listchars=eol:⏎,tab:>\ ,trail:·,extends:\#,nbsp:⎵
let g:LatexBox_loaded_matchparen=1
"let loaded_matchparen = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't look like matched tags, I suspect they're tab characters. Check your `listchars`.

Here's how to hide tabs:

```
:set listchars=tab:\ \ ;
```

---

Edit: I've just noticed that line 67 is all spaces so it's not tabs.

But it looks an awful lot like this plugin, are you using it?
https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides

Comment: I have this line in my vimrc `:set listchars=eol:⏎,tab:>\ ,trail:·,extends:\#,nbsp:⎵` only it applies to eol

Comment: I am using spf13 vim. In my vimrc.local there is nothing like `vim-indent-guides`

Comment: Ok I don't know how spf13 works but I can see it's included in .vimrc.bundle. remove it from there and delete​ it from your bundle directory and see how it looks

Comment: I got it. Thanks